# How to Loop through Ebay Kleinanzeigen Results. Can´t find right Type / Attribute

Tags: loops, imacros, extract

I have some troubles with my iMacros LOOP. The plan is to go to this website, search for a keyword and wait for the list of results. For example shoes see this link:

https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-schuhe/k0

My idea is to click on the first result and extract this to a csv file (csv file is already set up and works fine. Once on the item page, I want to extract the description / beschreibung and the URL which both works fine so far. See this link:

https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige/bmt-schuhe-schwarz/524917076-158-4466

Then go back and repeat the same steps for x amount of results.

The problem is that I can´t find the right code to extract the first result and loop through the rest of the results + extract each of them.

This is my code so far:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige/adidas-sport-freizeit-schuhe-gr-35/524737681-19-3157

**This should be the LOOP and titel extraction part***

**This is the part where the description and URL are extracted**
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=ID:viewad-description-text EXTRACT=TXT
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=extraction.csv
```

Hope someone can help me with this :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: The links you shared are local paths (probably) on your machine. Please create a link for them so they can be accessed by others

Comment: sorry for that. Hope it´s okay like this: https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-schuhe/k0

Comment: And the second page with the details / description: https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige/bmt-schuhe-schwarz/524917076-158-4466